# Firebase aggregate values over property without fetching all relevant documents

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have the following firebase structure:

```
{
    "company1": {
        "name": "Company One",
        "invoices": {
            "invoice1": {
                "amount": 300,
                "currency": "EUR",
                "timestamp": 1572608088
            },      
            "invoice2": {
                "amount": 460,
                "currency": "EUR",
                "timestamp": 1572608088
            }
        }
    }   
}
```

That is to say:
I have a collection `companies`.
There is a document for each company.
Each company has a subcollection `invoices`.

Each invoice has the properties `amount`,`currency`,`timestamp`.

Is there an efficient way of getting the sum of all amounts of invoices of a company **without** the need to fetch all relevant documents from firestore?
This would be the approach I came up with which would be rather inefficient:

`this.afs.collection('companies').document('company1').collection('invoices', ref => ref.where('timestamp', '>', 1556710488).where('timestamp', '>', 1572953978))`

I cannot just use a cloud function to increment a value as the requested time period is not known.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is there an efficient way of getting the sum of all amounts of invoices of a company without the need to fetch all relevant documents from Firestore?

Yes, you can add a new property in your company document named `totalAmount`, where you can store the total amount of all your invoices. Every time you add a new invoice, simply increment the `totalAmount` with the amount of the new invoice. Now in order to get the value of this new property a single document read is needed. Using this solution, you'll be charged with only **one** read operation and **not** with the total number of invoices that you have in your invoices subcollection.

Comment: This doesn't respect the fact that I want to calculate the amount in a specified time period and not the total amount.

Comment: In that case, the only solution I see is to query the entire collection using those `where()` calls.