# Handling big amount of data in Firebase or how avoid "where 'in'" restrictions?

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

Can anyone help me out with aggregation queries in Firestore. 
It seems that Firestore is all about restrictions and limits.

I've got two collections and I need to grab a certain amount of users using `.limit()` filtering, then I need to look for corresponding records in another collection.

The second query I make with `where in` filter, but apparently I can have only 10 items in the query array in `where in` filter.

The only way I managed to handle this request is:

```
           async ({ query }: Request, res: Response) => {
                const users: any = [];
                const ids: any = [];
                const stats: any = [];

                await firestore.collection('users').limit(30).get()
                    .then((snapshot) => {
                        let i = 1;
                        let d: any = [];

                        snapshot.forEach(doc => {
                            users.push(doc.data());

                            if (i <= 9) {
                                d.push(doc.data().id);
                                i++;
                            } else if (i === 10) {
                                d.push(doc.data().id);
                                i = 1;
                                ids.push(d);
                                d = [];
                            }

                        });

                    }).catch(console.log);

                const promises: any = [];

                ids.forEach((tens: any, index: number) => {
                    if (tens) {
                        promises.push(firestore.collection('users_statistic').
                            where('user_id', 'in', ids[index])
                            .get()
                            .then((snapshot) => {
                                const data: any = [];

                                snapshot.forEach(doc => data.push(doc.data()))
                                return data;
                            }))
                    }
                });

                await Promise.all(promises).then(stat => {
                    stat.forEach(t => {
                        stats.push(...(t as []));
                    })
                }).catch(console.log);

                const sortedStats: any = {};
                users.forEach((user: any) => {
                    sortedStats[user.id] = stats.filter((data: any) => data.user_id === user.id);
                });

                const totals = [];

                for (const key in sortedStats) {
                    if (sortedStats.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
                        const value = sortedStats[key];

                        const clicks = value.reduce((acc: any, v: any) => acc + v.clicks, 0);
                        const views = value.reduce((acc: any, v: any) => acc + v.page_views, 0);

                        totals.push({
                            ...users[key],
                            clicks,
                            views
                        })
                    }
                }

                res.status(200).send(totals);

}
```

1. I take the list of users
2. Take their ids and make batches of arrays which include up to ten ids
3. Make the list of requests and assign one array of ten ids (apparently that's not a good idea and I wanted to avoid it. I have to make many requests to Firestore DB)
4. By `Promise.all` I run all my promises
5. filtering and sorting results preparing the output data

I would appreciate any help here

Thanks in advance!

Comment: This is your third try at asking the same question, and while I can see that you're trying to focus the question, I still don't really understand what you're asking. If I post an answer saying something like "yes indeed, aggregation queries are hard on Firestore" would that be an answer you're looking for? Or is there something going wrong with the code you post? If so, which line is not doing what you want? It really helps if you write a single question into your post, that is concrete and focused.

Comment: Firestore is all about speed and scalability. In order to achieve those, limits are required.  In order to get the best out of Firestore, I suggest learning how to appreciate its strengths and work around its limitations.  https://medium.com/firebase-developers/the-top-10-things-to-know-about-firestore-when-choosing-a-database-for-your-app-a3b71b80d979

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen thanks for your answer! Yeah, that’s the second time I’m trying to find out how to overcome the restrictions on aggregation in Firestore. For that simple task I had to make 4 database connections except only 2. Yes, I completely agree that’s there can be some restrictions, but the code I writing seemed to me too wrong. That’s why I read through tons of official documentation and articles but anyway only restrictions.. Is the code above, the way I was trying to get data from Firebase,- making many db requests, adding one more place for unpredictable bugs while preparing query?

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen that’s what I was interested in... my code seemed to me a very bad practice to use. I thought I was doing something wrong. So I wanted to hear experienced people how they cope with aggregation in firestore.

Comment: @DougStevenson thanks for your answer! I really appreciate that

Comment: What is a good or bad practice is an opinion, which Stack Overflow isn't great for. But objectively, Firestore is probably not the best database to run ad-hoc aggregations on. If you need to do ad-hoc aggregations, you're probably better of using a database more suited for that, such as for example BigQuery, which excels at ad-hoc aggregation queries on arbitrarily large data sets. If you want to stick to Firestore, consider pre-aggregating the data, which means you store the aggregates into the database itself, and update them on every relevant write operation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you need to run a lot of ad-hoc aggregations, then Firestore is probably not the best database for you. In such a situation you're probably better of using a database more suited for ad-hoc queries, such as for example BigQuery, which excels at such aggregation queries on arbitrarily large data sets.

If you want to stick to Firestore, consider pre-aggregating the data, which means you store the aggregates into the database itself, and update them on every relevant write operation. This means that you won't be able to do them ad-hoc anymore, and that your write operations become more complex, but the good thing is that retrieving the aggregated information will be dead simple.

This is a common trade-off that you'll see with NoSQL databases: you'll need to tailor your data structure for your use-cases, and often will trade-off read/write scalability, and cost.

This topic has come up a few times, so also see:

- [Is it possible to run aggregation queries in Firestore?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58614592/is-it-possible-to-run-aggregation-queries-in-firestore/58614687#58614687), which is probably the answer I should've pointed you to straight away.
- [How to optimize Firestore Caching and Querymodeling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60663075/how-to-optimize-firestore-caching-and-querymodeling/60663699#60663699) (a similar question from last week)
- [How to create "likes count" Cloud Firestore aggregate function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59839565/how-to-create-likes-count-cloud-firestore-aggregate-function)
- [Firebase: Reduce number of reads for a large collection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60535751/firebase-reduce-number-of-reads-for-a-large-collection/60537294#60537294)
- [How to get firestore collection response in an Array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60463210/how-to-get-firestore-collection-response-in-an-array/60463288#60463288)
- [Firebase aggregate values over property without fetching all relevant documents](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58710688/firebase-aggregate-values-over-property-without-fetching-all-relevant-documents)

Comment: Thanks a lot, Frank for your answer! I have one more question. Is this possible to get the size of the collection without making the query "read all" I mean that I use 'limit' filter for my query because I don't need all the data in the collection. But when you use the "limit" filter there you can only see the size of the current request. I need this information for pagination so I can know the amount of pages expect. Here again I can see only one way - grap all the users (there are over 5k- what is not that good because it counts for database reads and come out too costy) and then filter data

Comment: Getting the count of the number of documents in a collection is the most common aggregation query. There is no built-in support for it, and your options here are the same as I mentioned for all other aggregation queries. There's an example in the documentation of how to store counters in documents, and keep them up to date: https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/solutions/counters

Comment: Yes, I thought there is a built-in way to get the number of records. So, I have nothing left but to play around with what it’s got